# When I run python script in python launcher it says return is outside function

Tags: python

```
menu = []  
with open("menu.txt") as f:  
    for line in f:
    itemName = line.split(",")[0]
    itemPrice = float(line.split("$")[-1])
    menu.append(itemName,itemPrice)
    return menu

print menu
```

I am using TextWrangler as my text editor and when I drag and drop the file.py into python launcher it says:

> SyntaxError: 'return' outside function.

I am indenting with a tab not 4 spaces.

Comment: There's no function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` can only be in a function. Otherwise what would it return *to*?

Take out the `return` and your code will work

Comment: Where would I place the file menu.txt to have it open when  I run the python script?

Comment: That's a new question, and should be asked as one if putting it in the same location as the .py isn't an option. Happy to have helped with this question though. Don't forget to [accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `return` in a function the you define.
**Example:**

```
def func():
    some code
    return value
```